# How can I have different operations in desktop and responsive view in angular material table row?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material-table

[Screenshot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO6Y7.jpg) I am using a mat table and in that mat table in mat-row, i want to route to another component in desktop view and expand the row in mobile view and in this I am using multiTemplateDataRows , but I am getting one extra blank row after each row. I have attached the scrrenshots for ref as well.

Comment: what have you done so far? can you please provide code?

Comment: Yes I am sharing the snippet

Comment: <mat-table #table [dataSource]="listConfigurations.dataSource" >

Comment: <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>

Comment: <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
      [routerLink]="routing_url"></mat-row>

Comment: <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" matRipple class="element-row" [class.expanded]="expandedElement == row"
   (click)="$event.stopPropagation(); expandRow(row);"></mat-row>

Comment: this is the snnippet

Comment: sir this is difficult  to understand can you create `https://stackblitz.com/`?

Comment: or if you can tell How can I create 2 mat-rows in mat table ?

Comment: https://kbmvnqbkrnm.angular.stackblitz.io  ---  This is just a ref.

Comment: I'm not able to open your link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbmvnqbkrnm?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.html